# npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead. with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I've installed node.js in my computer and when i run this command it gives me this error what can i do ???

```
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
```

Comment: You've shown us the error, but not the command you ran. The error message offers advice; did it not work?

Answer (score 1):

The old way of installing a package globally/locally has changed to
**`--location=global/local** instead of -g/-l

So let's say you want to install the create-react-app package globally you should do this:

**npm install --location=global create-react-app**

Answer (score 1):

I work on `npm v8.11.0` and `node v16.15.1`.

I've got warning as you:

> npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead

But now I am done following this:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.cmd edit **prefix -g** to **prefix --location=global**
```

Answer (score 1):

Write on your terminal or cmd :

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}
```

Enter your password of PC :

then try

```
npm install -g nodemon [see the solution pic][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

## This Fixes it

1. Open the node.js installation folder, eg. `C:\Program Files\nodejs`
2. Run notepad as **admin** and open `npm.cmd`
3. In the file, replace `prefix -g` with `prefix --location=global`, and Save
4. Do the same for `npx.cmd`

Check if the problem is fixed

If it is not working, update `npm` using `npm install npm@latest -g` and repeat the step on the new version if required.

[image: This shows notepad opened with the original file]

Answer (score 0):

npm has fixed this and all you need to do is update your npm version:

```
npm i -g npm@latest
```

I think as of version 8.13.